# Using Values from Results of Groupyby in Pandas for naming columns in new data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question:
I have a data-frame with columns ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
which I have grouped by two columns ('A', 'B') and then I used count function.
 `temp_df = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).count()`

the result is like this

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x_1 | y_1 | 3 | 3 |
|  | y_2 | 5 | 5 |
| x_2 | y_1 | 1 | 1 |
| x_3 | y_1 | 2 | 2 |
| x_4 | y_1 | 7 | 7 |
|  | y_2 | 8 | 8 |

and there is another point : Column `B` is binary, I mean either it's `y_1` or `y_2`.
but values in Column `A` can be anything.
Also there is something else ,if we have `x_1 --> y_2` in data-frame, there must be `x_1 --> y_1` and this is guaranteed.
Now I want another data-frame with these columns:

| A | y_1 | y_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x_1 | 3 | 5 |
| x_2 | 1 | 0 |
| x_3 | 2 | 0 |
| x_4 | 7 | 8 |

but I don't know how to do it.

p.s: I know that I can use for loop but it's inefficient, I want to use pandas functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Please replace `:` with a space to format your table. Also, are C and D always identical ?

Comment: @joao :  yes, but if omitting one of them makes things easier, there is no limitation for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `unstack` the `B` level while filling the missings of either `y_1` or `y_2` with 0. Then we select the `C` column's values as `D` can be omitted as mentioned in the comments:

```
>>> df.unstack("B", fill_value=0).C

B    y_1  y_2
A
x_1    3    5
x_2    1    0
x_3    2    0
x_4    7    8
```

If you want to get rid of `B` on top left (which is put there as the *name* of the columns), you can further rename that axis to `None`:

```
>>> df.unstack("B", fill_value=0).C.rename_axis(columns=None)

     y_1  y_2
A
x_1    3    5
x_2    1    0
x_3    2    0
x_4    7    8
```

`A` is an index here, to make it a column, we can reset the index:

```
>>> df.unstack("B", fill_value=0).C.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

     A  y_1  y_2
0  x_1    3    5
1  x_2    1    0
2  x_3    2    0
3  x_4    7    8
```

Comment: Tnx, but I came up with another question, I want column ```A``` to be also a column, not index, what should I do?

Comment: @MehrdadRiyahi We reset the index to make it a column; edited the answer hope it helps.